# Formal Proof of "No Largest Number"

Tags: formal-proofs

I need to create a formal proof of there not being the largest number, with only the definition of "less than" being given with Peano arithmetic. $s(x)$ means successor of $x$ or $x + 1$.

$$
\text{Premise}\\
\forall x\forall y (x \lt y \iff \exists z(x + s(z) = y)\\
\text{Prove}\\
\forall x \exists y (x < y)
$$

I've tried proof by contradiction, but the resources online don't seem to translate well into a formal proof. In particular, the strategy of "assume there is a largest number, add one, done" doesn't really translate with formal proof steps.

Comment: Can you prove $\forall x ~(x \lt s(x))$?

Comment: I can try. I am only really allowed that premise, so I don't think I can use any of the other Peano rules. Also did you edit my question? I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Other MSE users with enough reputation can edit your questions, but I don't think Robert's edits are justifiable.I have flagged that.

Comment: It suffices to let $y=x+s(x)$. Then $x\lt y$ is guaranteed by letting $z=x$.

Comment: So do you actually need a pedantic formal first order logic explicit rules of inference proof, or are you looking for an informal proof where the arithmetic axioms are used explicitly but the rest is informal?

Comment: I need the former. With only the premise I gave, I need to give explicit steps like $\forall$ elimination/introduction, $\exists$ elimination/introduction, etc.

Comment: My main problem has been since the premise is a biconditional, I don't know how I would produce an absolute statement like x < y from that. The only other "relevant" topic in my class is Peano induction, but I don't really see how that would help

Comment: From $\forall x \forall y( x < y \iff \exists z ( \dots))$ infer $x < y \iff \exists z ( \dots))$ then infer $\exists z (\dots) \to x < y$ then use that.

Comment: I don't see how that second inference benefits me in any way. you're just saying the biconditional works the other direction. But that's still just a "conditional". You don't have any concrete information if that makes sense.

Comment: @Kevin You should be able to tell that a statement of the form $A \to B$ is useful when you are trying to prove $B$.

Comment: @RobArthan All I did was put the math formulas $s(x), x,$ and $x+1$ in MathJax.  I don't know how those other words got removed, but I certainly didn't intend to do that.  I think someone else may have been editing at the same time I was -- perhaps the two edits got combined somehow under my name.

Comment: Do you know that $s(0)=1$?

Comment: In response to your last comment, @DanielV I understand that if I know $A \to B$ and I have $A$, then I have $B$. In your example, $A$ would be $\exists z (x + s(z) = y)$ but I don't know where I could just pull that out of nowhere. My guess would be to assume $\neg A$ and try to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved!

The key to solving this was with "creating the right half" of the original premise: $\exists z (x + s(z) = y)$

Comment: Well done Kevin! ... But maybe hide your answer so you won't give it away to any other students?

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to prove that for all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $x$ is less than $y$. To do that, imagine you are given an $x$ (maybe $x=99$) and try to come up with a $y$ that is greater than $x$. How about $x + 1$ (i.e., $100$ if $x = 99$)? So there's your proof: as $y = x + 1 > x$ for any $x$, then for all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $x < y$.

Proof by contradiction is best regarded as a last resort: to be used only if working forward from the positive information that you have isn't getting you anywhere.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Although since I need step-by-step proof steps like the universal introduction/elimination, I don't know if this translates so well

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of Barry Cipra in the comments:

$$\forall x \exists y~(y=s(x)) \\
\forall x \exists y \exists w ~(x+y=x+s(x)=w) \\
(\forall x \exists z (=x)~(x +s(z)=w)) \Rightarrow x \lt w \Rightarrow \exists w~(x \lt w)$$

Comment: I don't entirely understand this, especially the last step. But your first line seems to just come from nowhere. May I remind you that I **only** get the definition of less than. I could just assume that first step, but that doesn't really help I don't think.

Comment: The first step just says that $s$ is a function that is defined on your entire domain on discourse.  The last step is *modus ponens*.